# R: extract the last two numbers in a variable

Tags: r, merge, extract

I have two datasets (data1 and data2).
Data1 has (one of many) a column named: B233333**91**
Data2 has a column called id_number, where id numbers are listed (e.g. 3444444**91**)

I need to extract the last two digits (**91**) from the variable in data1 and merge it with the last two digits of the id number in data2 in column id_number
Since the last two digits represents an individual.

E.g.:

Data1:
columns: -> B23333391..... and so on

Data2:
columns: -> **id_number**

```
               344444491
               and so on....
```

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. You can use a `dplyr` pipeline to format an id variable in both dataframes using `substr()`. The last two digits can be extracted with `nchar()`. After that you can merge using `left_join()`. Here the code with simulated data similar to those shared by you:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df1 <- data.frame(Var1=c('B23333391'),Val1=1,stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(Varid=c('344444491'),Val2=1,stringsAsFactors = F) 
#Merge
dfnew <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(id=substr(Var1,nchar(Var1)-1,nchar(Var1))) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(id=substr(Varid,nchar(Varid)-1,nchar(Varid))))
```

Output:

```
       Var1 Val1 id     Varid Val2
1 B23333391    1 91 344444491    1
```